# Haskell - How to modify existing function values

Tags: haskell

i have a basic question regarding Haskell that boggles my mind since i am new to functional programming.

i've got simple functions for example

```
foo 1 1 = 0
foo 1 2 = 1
foo 2 1 = 1
foo 2 2 = 0
```

and i want to change the function values depending on a condition via another function (for example from 1 to 0, if the value is 1). How can i do that? I'm comming from python and am somehow stuck in the way of thought that i can simply assign the new value in the function body.

im trying something along this lines:

```
changeValue x y
        |(foo x y == 1) = foo x y = 0
```

A little hint would be appreciated, since it feels like a simple question that i just can't find a solution for. Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible in Haskell. Nor in Python, for that matter; how about showing us some actual working Python code that uses the kind of mutation that you actually have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake in thinking about those functions like variables in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe having a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions helps? Think of haskell functions as mathematical functions, there's no assignment there either.

Anyway, you can ask an other function for a value to compare to, and e.g. in that case return `1`:

```
foo 0 1                    = 1
foo x y
  | otherfunction x y == 7 = 1
  | otherwise              = 0
```

Comment: I think what i really want to do is to change the function permanently or rather overwrite it. I was just a bit confused :)